# java program assertion failed

Tags: java, assertion

I made a huge project on java. The code is over 1000 lines long, and there are lots of methods and calling. I don't want to post the code here since then this question would probably get flagged.

Anyways, for some reason whenever I try to run my program, it does not work even though there are no errors. Instead, a new window pops up that says, Assertion Failed!

It says: 
Assertion Failed!
Program: (program location)
File: (src_jikes something)
Line: 5699

Expression: ptr && "failed dynamic_cast<> in DYNAMIC_CAST"

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)

I can either Abort, Retry, or Ignore this error message.

All my other programs work by the way.

Luckily, I still have my code. But I just can't run it. Any reason to why this is? Please help.

Edit: When I click retry, it says:

"The environment (not your program) has crashed.
The error is caused by a bug in the environment and is not your fault!
Details about the crash have been saved in the file (file location).
If possible, email this file to readybugs@hsa.on.ca
Here are some details about the crash:
Cause of Crash: Breakpoint Reached");

EDIT 2: APPARENTLY IT ONLY DOESN'T WORK WHEN I ADD AN ASCII ART

The ASCII art is this:

```
public void weezing ()
{
System.out.println ("                  __....____,'  `-.");
System.out.println ("         ,''-..-''          '-    |       ..      _.._");
System.out.println ("         |        _, .,           '._    /  `'''''    |");
System.out.println ("        .'         _____             `.,'     ____     `.");
System.out.println ("     _,' _.'      \\  |  ''--..        '       \\__ `'-.   `.");
System.out.println ("    | ,''|/        `-.______,'      `     ' |\\_  `''''  .  \\");
System.out.println ("    .'---'      _____             . '   `   |,''''-._  ' \\  .");
System.out.println ("   /   __..--''|___/ '-.._/|         ,'       ___    `. \\ \\ '_");
System.out.println ("  . .'...-----'''----.._.' |-.      |        | ,.`'.   \\ `'   |");
System.out.println ("  | `'                  '-.'-'      `.        \\`._`.\\   |.  .-'");
System.out.println (".'        _..._                 .              `._  ,   `.' |");
System.out.println (" `.    ,''_....`'.               |                ''       .");
System.out.println ("  |    | |     | |             -'   `,                    /");
System.out.println ("  `,.  `._`---'_,'  ,-.    '        ' `-.             _   |");
System.out.println ("  ,\\ `._  |___|  _,'  |  `    \\        . /-.__     _.' `-'");
System.out.println ("  \\ `.._`-._ _.-'_,.--'        |        `.    |  ,'");
System.out.println ("   `-'\\ `-. ' ,'_         `-..'       .-'    /  /");
System.out.println ("       `._.---._ `'----.        .   ,'.   _.'  /");
System.out.println ("         `.     `'-.._/       -" ,-" `.`-'      `.");
System.out.println ("           `.,       .-'    _    |     | .     ) |");
System.out.println ("             '._  ,'`----''`.    |     ' `'       .");
System.out.println ("                ''           `--'       \\`      ,''");
System.out.println ("                                          `-._,-'");
}
```

Comment: How can it ask you to see the visual C++ assert documentation if you are writing in java?

Comment: I don't know man. First time this happened to me.

Comment: What kind of JDK are you using? Jikes?

Comment: i'm using Ready-to-Program java

Comment: Did you change anything in the code to cause an error?

Comment: It looks like a bug with RTP/Turing. Why don't you do what the error message says and send in the crash report? In the meantime, post your code. This is Stack Overflow, where you get downvoted for *not* posting code.

Comment: Yes, I added in a bit of code. I'll try taking that piece of code out.

Comment: Okay, so I tried emailing the crash report but it didn't send. The delivery failed permanently due to a DNS error and the domain name was not found

Comment: @MarsAtomic my code is really long (about 1100 lines). I posted only like 70 lines and got downvoted for posting too much code.

Comment: @Laurel LOL it works when I took that part of code out

Comment: You need to learn how to post a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) of code. The crash message says that it was caused by hitting a breakpoint. Did you add a breakpoint into your code? Post the part of code that you added before the problem occurred.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Okay, so I added just one ASCII art picture and the code stops working and the error comes. If I remove the ASCII art, the code works just fine.

Comment: @MarsAtomic the ASCII art is in my edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, try removing any code that you added right before it stops compiling.

99.99999999% of the time, the problem is solved this way.

Also, look more carefully at what you copy/paste into your code, even if it's just ASCII art.

Edit: The problem is unescaped quotes. Gives a `bad operand type String for unary operator '---'`

Happens at this line:

```
System.out.println ("         `.     `'-.._/       -" ,-" `.`-'      `.");
```

...Full fix:

```
public static void weezing ()
{
System.out.println ("                  __....____,'  `-.");
System.out.println ("         ,''-..-''          '-    |       ..      _.._");
System.out.println ("         |        _, .,           '._    /  `'''''    |");
System.out.println ("        .'         _____             `.,'     ____     `.");
System.out.println ("     _,' _.'      \\  |  ''--..        '       \\__ `'-.   `.");
System.out.println ("    | ,''|/        `-.______,'      `     ' |\\_  `''''  .  \\");
System.out.println ("    .'---'      _____             . '   `   |,''''-._  ' \\  .");
System.out.println ("   /   __..--''|___/ '-.._/|         ,'       ___    `. \\ \\ '_");
System.out.println ("  . .'...-----'''----.._.' |-.      |        | ,.`'.   \\ `'   |");
System.out.println ("  | `'                  '-.'-'      `.        \\`._`.\\   |.  .-'");
System.out.println (".'        _..._                 .              `._  ,   `.' |");
System.out.println (" `.    ,''_....`'.               |                ''       .");
System.out.println ("  |    | |     | |             -'   `,                    /");
System.out.println ("  `,.  `._`---'_,'  ,-.    '        ' `-.             _   |");
System.out.println ("  ,\\ `._  |___|  _,'  |  `    \\        . /-.__     _.' `-'");
System.out.println ("  \\ `.._`-._ _.-'_,.--'        |        `.    |  ,'");
System.out.println ("   `-'\\ `-. ' ,'_         `-..'       .-'    /  /");
System.out.println ("       `._.---._ `'----.        .   ,'.   _.'  /");
System.out.println ("         `.     `'-.._/       -\" ,-\" `.`-'      `.");
System.out.println ("           `.,       .-'    _    |     | .     ) |");
System.out.println ("             '._  ,'`----''`.    |     ' `'       .");
System.out.println ("                ''           `--'       \\`      ,''");
System.out.println ("                                          `-._,-'");
}
```

Comment: my ASCII art picture is in my edited question. How can I run the program with the ASCII art?

Comment: You sir, are a GOD